# what is hostname?

Tags: networking

I have been reading a book about network programming but I am confused about some terminology,
**hostname**, **fqdn** and **canonical**. I know something about fqdn, but what's the difference among them? I really don't understand what is a hostname.

Comment: [HOSTNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) and [Canonical Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)

Comment: [EQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host name is nothing but it is a label name which is assigned to a device when it is connecting with a network.  for example In internet a host name of the domain name assign to a local computer. en.wikipedia.org is an example of host name(en is a host name), (wikipedia.org) is a domain name.

Comment: what is the use of setting hostname in production

When in production, I have seen some people do

hostnamectl set-hostname <what-ever>
later to put it in `nano etc/hosts`

99% tutorials omit this tho, what is the use of this?
Found this link on the matter but still don't quite understand it.

Comment: https://learn.akamai.com/en-us/webhelp/adaptive-media-delivery/adaptive-media-delivery-implementation-guide/GUID-0EA5FB59-3184-4BE3-A522-E85572DDA8CA.html